# I want to pray and meditate like a Buddhist, but I do not know how because I am Arab and I have not found sources in Arabic so can you guide me

Tags: philosophy

I want to pray and meditate like a Buddhist, but I do not know how because I am Arab and I have not found sources in Arabic so can you guide me

Comment: Where are you from, friend? I also live in 
Arabia.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this PDF copy](https://scdd.sfo2.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/uploads/original/3X/f/7/f72e1eaee09cd2a24a8f79663866613a9711c5ea.pdf) of the Dhammapada in Arabic online. I don't read Arabic, so I cannot guarantee the authenticity of this copy.

The [Metta Sutta (خطبة البودا عن المحبه) in Arabic](https://suttacentral.net/snp1.8/ar/dhammarakkhita) translated by Ven. Dhammarakkhita and hosted on SuttaCentral.

You can read [AccessToInsight.org in Arabic](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=ar&u=https://www.accesstoinsight.org/) through Google Translate. This contains a large collection of the Pali Canon. For e.g. the [Dhammacakkappavattana Sutta in Arabic](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=ar&u=https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn56/sn56.011.than.html) translated using Google Translate. This is the discourse where the Buddha declared his teachings just after his enlightenment, and set the wheel of the Dhamma in motion.

I have found and used Google Translate to translate some important prayers/ chants/ statements here.

This is the undertaking of the five precepts (قواعد التدريب الخمسة):

> 1. أتعهد بمبدأ الامتناع عن تدمير الكائنات الحية.
> 2. أتعهد بالامتناع عن أخذ ما لم يؤخذ.
> 3. أتعهد بمبدأ الامتناع عن سوء السلوك الجنسي.
> 4. أتعهد بالامتناع عن الكلام غير الصحيح.
> 5. أتعهد بالامتناع عن المسكرات والمخدرات التي تؤدي إلى الإهمال.

For meditation, I'm again putting through Google Translate, the pages from Ven. Yuttadhammo's e-book How to Meditate:

- [Chapter One: What Is Meditation (الفصل الأول: ما هو التأمل)](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=ar&u=https://www.sirimangalo.org/text/how-to-meditate/chapter-one-what-is-meditation/)
- [Chapter Two: Sitting Meditation (الفصل الثاني: جلوس التأمل)](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=ar&u=https://www.sirimangalo.org/text/how-to-meditate/chapter-two-sitting-meditation/)
- [Chapter Three: Walking Meditation (الفصل الثالث: المشي التأمل)](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=ar&u=https://www.sirimangalo.org/text/how-to-meditate/chapter-three-walking-meditation/)
- [Chapter Four: Fundamentals (الفصل الرابع: الأساسيات)](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=ar&u=http://www.sirimangalo.org/articles/how-to-meditate/chapter-four-fundamentals/)
- [Chapter Five: Mindful Prostration (الفصل الخامس: السجود اليقظ)](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=ar&u=https://www.sirimangalo.org/text/how-to-meditate/chapter-five-mindful-prostration/)
- [Chapter Six: Daily Life (الفصل السادس: الحياة اليومية)](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=ar&u=https://www.sirimangalo.org/text/how-to-meditate/chapter-six-daily-life/)
- [Appendix: Illustrations (الملحق: الرسوم التوضيحية)](https://www.sirimangalo.org/text/how-to-meditate/appendix-illustrations/)

Answer (score 1):

real Buddhist meditation is meditation upon/development of the [clear light luminous mind](https://www.bookdepository.com/Mind-Clear-Light-Dalai-Lama-XIV/9780743244695), free from impure emotions, thoughts and desires, as follows:

> Luminous, monks, is the mind. And it is freed from incoming
> defilements. The well-instructed disciple of the noble ones discerns
> that as it actually is present, which is why I tell you that — for the
> well-instructed disciple of the noble ones — there is development of
> the mind.
>
> [Pabhassara
> Sutta: Luminous](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an01/an01.049.than.html)

Again:

> Endowed with this noble aggregate of virtue, this noble restraint over
> the sense faculties, this noble mindfulness & alertness, he seeks out
> a secluded dwelling: a wilderness, the shade of a tree, a mountain, a
> glen, a hillside cave, a charnel ground, a forest grove, the open air,
> a heap of straw. After his meal, returning from his alms round, he
> sits down, crosses his legs, holds his body erect, and brings
> mindfulness to the fore. Abandoning covetousness with regard to the
> world, he dwells with an awareness devoid of covetousness. He cleanses
> his mind of covetousness. Abandoning ill will & anger, he dwells with
> an awareness devoid of ill will, sympathetic with the welfare of all
> living beings. He cleanses his mind of ill will & anger. Abandoning
> sloth & drowsiness, he dwells with an awareness devoid of sloth &
> drowsiness, mindful, alert, percipient of light. He cleanses his mind
> of sloth & drowsiness. Abandoning restlessness & anxiety, he dwells
> undisturbed, his mind inwardly stilled. He cleanses his mind of
> restlessness & anxiety. Abandoning uncertainty, he dwells having
> crossed over uncertainty, with no perplexity with regard to skillful
> mental qualities. He cleanses his mind of uncertainty.
>
> [Mahatanhasankhaya
> Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.038.than.html)

Again:

> And what is the faculty of concentration? There is the case where a
> monk, a disciple of the noble ones, making it his object to let go,
> attains concentration, attains singleness of mind.
>
> [Indriya-vibhanga
> Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn48/sn48.010.than.html)

This can be found in Arabic, in [Surah Al-Falaq](https://quran.com/113).

If you wish to serve Budddhism, you can translate the above Buddha quotes into Arabic and publish them on an internet blog.